# I get a maximum recursion depth error in a relatively simple while loop, help to convert to iterative?

Tags: python-2.7, recursion, iteration

I'm making a poker game and this is the betting round stage where it checks whether the betting is over:

```
def bettingRound():
    end = False
    while end == False:
        action1 = raw_input(str(playGame().player1)[9:] + ", what is your move? (r/c/f):")
    if action1 == 'f':
        playGame().player2.score = playGame().player2.score + 1
        game().winner = str(playGame().player2)[9:]
        end = True
    elif action1 == 'r':
        raiseAmount1 = raw_input("Raise by: ")
        playGame().player1.money = playGame().player1.money - raiseAmount1
        Table.pot = Table.pot + raiseAmount1
        end = False
    elif action1 == 'c':
        end = False
    action2 = raw_input(str(playGame().player2)[9:] + ", what is your move? (r/c/f):")
    if action2 == 'f':
        playGame().player1.score = playGame().player1.score + 1
        game().winner = str(playGame().player1)[9:]
        end = True
    elif action2 == 'r':
        raiseAmount2 = raw_input("Raise by: ")
        playGame().player2.money = playGame().player2.money - raiseAmount1 - raiseAmount2 
        Table.pot = Table.pot + raiseAmount1 + raiseAmount2
        end = False
    elif action2 == 'c':
        if action1 ==  'r':
            playGame().player2.money = playGame().player2.money - raiseAmount1
            Table.pot = Table.pot + raiseAmount1
            end = False
        if action1 == 'c':
            end = True
```

The weird thing is that it is not able to print even the first raw_input statement. I have tried increasing the maximum recursion depth but I get a stack overflow. Looking at other questions the simple solution is to make the algorithm iterative rather than recursive, yet I'm unsure about how to go about this.

PS: Since there is rather a lot of code going on I have put the full program here (128 lines): http://pastebin.com/DSBACdB6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the solution so I could keep it recursive (much more useful in the long run). I had to make a separate player class:

```
class Players:
    player1 = None
    player2 = None

def findPlayers():
    if randint(0,100) >= 50: 
        Players.player1 = ai
        Players.player2 = human
    else:
        Players.player1 = human
        Players.player2 = ai
```

Answer (score 0):

You should refactor your code to have a Game class where you store some state of the game instead of calling newGame() so that in bettingRound you'll avoid to create a new infinite loop when trying to update the players money. After creating a class you'll see more opportunity to refactor your functions into methods.